# SQL: subtracting value in a table from another table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, myisam

First time question here. I'm trying to subtract the stock in table `SS_Products` by a quantity in `EXPOS.INV`. This is the code that I have tried:

```
UPDATE SS_products SS 
SET SS.nb_stock = (SELECT SS.nb_stock - EX.Qty 
                   FROM EXPOS_INV EX
                   WHERE  SS.product_code = EX.Barcode)
```

The code works, it updates the `nb_stock` where the lines match between the 2 tables, but it nulls it on every other line.

I tried adding an Inner Join:

```
UPDATE SS_products SS 
SET SS.nb_stock = (SELECT SS.nb_stock - EX.Qty 
                   FROM EXPOS_INV EX
                   WHERE SS.product_code = EX.Barcode)
INNER JOIN EXPOS_INV ON SS_products.product_code = EXPOS_INV.Barcode
```

This one doesn't go through. I also tried with a `WHERE` but it doesn't take any clause from `EXPOS_INV`

Following an answer, I tried the `Where Exists` but it returned a bunch of truncate messages for unrelated lines.

I followed a comment for a basic example, and I came up with this code

```
UPDATE 
    SS_products
SET 
    SS_products.nb_stock = (Select SS.nb_stock - EX.Qty from EXPOS_INV EX
                   Where SS.product_code = EX.Barcode)
FROM 
    SS_products
    INNER JOIN EXPOS_INV ON SS_products.product_code = EXPOS_INV.Barcode
Where
    SS_products.product_code = EXPOS_INV.Barcode
```

this returns a syntax error.

Comment: take a lok at a basic example: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using `where` if the matching row exists:

```
UPDATE SS_products SS 
    SET SS.nb_stock = (Select SS.nb_stock - EX.Qty
                       from EXPOS_INV EX
                       Where SS.product_code = EX.Barcode
                      )
    WHERE EXISTS (Select SS.nb_stock - EX.Qty
                  from EXPOS_INV EX
                  Where SS.product_code = EX.Barcode
                 );
```